# how to override nokia basic searchbox input style?

Tags: html, css, here-api

I am trying the basic searchbox feature on the API doc http://api.maps.nokia.com/places/BasicSearchBoxExample.html

The HERE api searchbox is too short, I would like to style it. 
Here is my html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="basicSearchBox"></div>
</div>
```

I don't have access to the below html section (it was generated by the reference in the header `<script src="http://api.maps.nokia.com/places/beta3/jsPlacesAPI.js"></script>` )

How do I style the input box 'nokia-searchbox-input' to increase the height?

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="basicSearchBox" class="nokia-places-general-searchbox">
    <div class="nokia-searchbox">
      <input class="nokia-searchbox-input" type="text" rel="searchbox-input">
      <input class="nokia-searchbox-button" type="button" rel="searchbox-button" value="Search">
      <div rel="searchbox-list" class="nokia-searchbox-list" style="display: none;">
        <div class="nokia-searchbox-list-border"></div>
        <dl class="suggest-current"></dl>
        <dl class="suggest-saved"></dl>
        <dl class="suggest-nokia"></dl>
        <dl class="suggest-search"></dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding, but you should be able to just add this to your CSS:

```
.nokia-places-general-searchbox .nokia-searchbox-input {
    height: 20px; /* whatever you want the height to be */
}
```

Comment: that fixed it! thank you. could you please explain why only 2 classes are needed?

Comment: The CSS that comes along with that search component includes a definition of styles for that element on line 123: (http://api.maps.nokia.com/places/beta3/css/ovi-places-general.css) In order to override that, you need to either be *more* specific with classes (add another to the stack) or have the same specificity (use the same classes) and come later in the page than the original, overridden definition.

Comment: Wow. That sounded better in my head. Let me know if any/none of that made sense.